# Is Lysol a good treatment for the musky AC smell?

Tags: ac, corolla, smell

So i bought my BRAND NEW Corolla 6 months ago. Recently i started smelling a musky smell coimg out of the AC. The smell is especially persistent when the AC is off (yes OFF, not ON)

So I went to the dealership, and they told me that was okay blah blah . There is nothing they could do. They told this was because the AC leaves some water residue in the pipes, and later that water gets mildew . Crazy  ?

I watched youtube videos on how to fix this. [There was a guy explaining how to apply Lysol right into the outside AC intake.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JYKN3bypcT0) So I did, and the smell went away temporarily.

It's been a week. Then the smell started all over again.

I took my car to the dealership again, and they asked me if I wanted to change the cabin filter, so I did (spend $100) . But the smell did not go away .

Is there anything I did wrong ? Maybe I should have applied Lysol from the very beginning as a preventative measure . What should I do, when I get my second car ? Are there any specific maintanence tricks I should know about

Comment: You may have to replace all of the air ducts in the car. They can trap odors and mildew.

Comment: Oh no . my heart is trembling . it's a new car . how come ?

Comment: If it is a brand new car then the onus in on the seller to fix the problem. If the odor 'came' with the car and it is under warranty they are obligated to fix it. They will ignore you if they know the problem is 'built in' at the factory, so you may actually have to seek legal action against them, but  pester them first to see if they are cooperative.

Comment: Really like your question but I believe the answer I linked should have some helpful suggestions.  If you need help understanding any aspects of an answer or the question, please don't hesitate to ask!  Cheers.